# Maven build not running

Tags: maven-2

i have created a maven build of my project.The build was succesfull.But when i deploy it on server (apache tomcat 6) it gives various errors regarding jar files.But those jar files are available on the class path.But when i keep those jar files in the lib directory of server then that error gets resolved.So,anyone having any idea regarding this..I have done anything wrong in building using maven.

My pom.xml

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    Test1
    Test1
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    war
    Test1
    http://maven.apache.org

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>central</id>
        <name>Maven Repository Switchboard</name>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2</url>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt.core</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.ow2.orchestra.eclipse.birt.report.engine</artifactId>
        <version>3.7.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>openforecast</groupId>
        <artifactId>openforecast</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.16</version>
        <scope>system</scope>
        <systemPath>D:/testing/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/OpenForecast-0.5.0.jar</systemPath>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-math</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jsci</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsci</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>taglibs</groupId>
        <artifactId>standard</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-taglib</artifactId>
        <version>1.3.10</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts-bean</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.7</version>
        <type>tld</type>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jtds</groupId>
        <artifactId>jtds</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <properties>
                    <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
                    <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
                </properties>
                <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <packagingExcludes>D:/Test1/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Probably because the scope was set to `provided`.  If you tell us exactly which jars you were having trouble with, and can show us the full dependency section of your POM, we can probably resolve this for you.

Answer (score 3):

You don't deploy a jar on a Tomcat : you deploy a war file.
The war contains a WEB-INF/lib folder which contains your libraries.

The lib folder at the Tomcat root is used only for libraries shared between all deployed applications. For example, the database driver.

Check that your Maven dependencies are not in scope **provided**.
They should be included in your *WEB-INF/lib* folder.

Comment: Thanks for the reply I am sharing my pom.xml

Comment: I think he means dependencies jar files.

Answer (score 0):

First things like your dependency to the servlet api:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Must have a scope "provided" like this which means they will be needed for compiling but in the runtime it will be provided by Tomcat in this case.

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
  <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
  <version>2.5</version>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

The following:

openforecast
   openforecast
   1.0.16
   system
   D:/testing/WebContent/WEB-INF/lib/OpenForecast-0.5.0.jar

indicates you are not using a Repository which is a real must. Never use system scoped dependencies in your build, cause they will make you build environment specific.
Start using a repository manager (Nexus, Artifactory or Archive) and install the openforecast there.
And it's [bad practice to define repositories](http://www.sonatype.com/people/2009/02/why-putting-repositories-in-your-poms-is-a-bad-idea/) in your pom and in particular Maven Central like you did.

If you have defined the following in your pom as you have:

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>ISO-8859-1</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>
```

The configuration of the [maven-compiler-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/compile-mojo.html#encoding) is not needed like this, cause the encoding parameter uses as default the above property.

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
        <properties>
            <maven.compiler.target>1.6</maven.compiler.target>
            <maven.compiler.source>1.6</maven.compiler.source>
        </properties>
        <encoding>ISO-8859-1</encoding>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

you can use the following:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But you must define the version of your used plugins:

```
 <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
    <configuration>
        <source>1.6</source>
        <target>1.6</target>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The best to do is using a pluginManagement section.

One other thing which comes to my mind is that your are using an old maven-war-plugin and you are using absolute paths in your configuration which you should avoid under any circumstances.

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.1</version>
   <configuration>
     <packagingExcludes>D:/Test1/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

The up-to-date version is 2.2 as [the web-site says](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/). If you need to exclude things like this you should do it in the following way:

```
<plugin>
   <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>2.2</version>
   <configuration>
     <packagingExcludes>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</packagingExcludes>
   </configuration>
</plugin>
```

But in this case i don't understand why you like to exclude the web.xml, cause it's an essential part of a war file. May be you can elaborate that a little bit more.

Comment: Hi khmarbaise thanks for the reply since i am new to maven so i have made the changes specified by you but still i am facing the following exception..                                                            org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410
 org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile

Comment: i didn't find the maven dependency for openforecast thats why i added it from the system.

Comment: khmarbaise should i use nexus for all the dependencies or only for the dependency which are not available in maven repository ?

Comment: Hi, i am still facing the same error as mentioned above..maven build still not running.

Comment: @user1169095 Nexus is exactly for dependencies which are not in Maven central or in other repositories in the wild. Furthermore what does "build still not running" mean? Error messages? Can you post the output via -X and messages?

Comment: when i rum my maven build i am facing following error                                                                                                                                   org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.struts.taglib.html.FormTag
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:500)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:410)

Comment: Sounds you missed a tag library in your jsp/jspx etc. files.

Comment: I have checked the jsp page i have defined a tag library and tag-lib jar is also present.

Comment: The struts-taglib contains the mentioned class. Just try to remove the "runtime" scope of the dependency and recheck. Have you checked if the struts-taglib is contained in the war file ?

Comment: Ya i have checked the struts-taglib is not present in the lib folder where the eclipse deploys the application.why is it so.i have mentioned the dependency in pom.xml for struts-tablib .

Comment: Cause you defined it as runtime scope. The first recommendation i can give is to test such things first with Maven itself on command line and not inside Eclipse.

Comment: Have you check to do a mvn clean package on the command line ? NOT in Eclipse.

Comment: Ya i ahve done mvn clean and again created a new build but still the same problem.But when i manually put struts-taglib.jar in lib folder of the build then its works fine..

Comment: i want to define dbconnection properties file in pom.xml how can i specify it.